# selecting angular2 elements in css

Tags: css, angular2-forms

I have the following markup in angular2

```
<form [formGroup]="createPasswordForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickCreatePassword(createPassword)">
```

how do I select this element in css
I tried the following but it does not seem to work

```
form[\[formGroup\]="createPasswordForm"]
```

and

```
form[formGroup="createPasswordForm"]
```

Comment: Just give it an ID or something. As you can see if you look at the generated HTML, `[formGroup]` is not a "real" attribute which is present in the HTML, and therefore cannot be addressed by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You are used like this:-

```
<form id="createPasswordForm" [formGroup]="createPasswordForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickCreatePassword(createPassword)">
```

**component.css:-**

```
#createPasswordForm{
 // Write a css code here
}
```

[formGroup] is not a "real" attribute of the html this is the property of formGroup.